# Facebook notification on third party software

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a fb api that allows user to get fb notification or latest wall post by friend on their own website? this means that the software will requires user fb credential.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create your own site that gets data from the users latest wall posts, you can use the Facebook Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

To pull most recent wall posts (in JSON format), use:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=<UserTokenHere>`

The Facebook Graph API site above gives lots of good info on how to use this. If you are trying to do something else, please clarify your question.

Cheers!